# PHP: Write comma to csv file

Tags: php, csv

I've got a form which submits data to a csv file.
When a user inputs a comma to a field, it destroys my csv structure.
I want to convert inputted commas so that they can get displayed as a character.

I tried this:

```
$_POST["field"] = str_replace(",", "','", $_POST["field"]);
```

Comment: What are you using to generate the CSV file?

Comment: use phpExcel to produce result ..

Comment: The correct CSV structure is that each column should be wrapped with double quotes, and then any double quotes inside to be escaped.

Comment: Instead of writing your own escaping and formatting mechanism, consider using [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Comment: phpExcel is depricated for now ! see https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel
below is right answer "use fputcsv() to write, and fgetcsv() to read the file"  its a safe and correct way !  versus just replace POST, that can overflowed your serv

Answer (score 5):

Use html encoding for instant relief , but still my recommendation to use phpExcel

```
$comma="&#44";
$_POST["field"] = str_replace(",", $comma, $_POST["field"]);
```

Comment: Why on earth would you recommend a whole other library, when PHP supports CSV out of the box with `fputcsv` and `fgetcsv`? Also, if you're going to encode one thing, why not encode the entire string properly instead of just hacking in a single HTML entity?

Comment: This worked well, thanks! If you don't want to use fputcsv() this solution is very good.

Comment: @JonStirling , CSV stands for comma seperated values. You can't achieve extra functionalites because CSV file doesn't support font styles etc .. so i recommended not emphasized .. overall , thanks for your useful advice.

Comment: thanx, correct answer! Cause not all *.csv imports  clearly understand where right commas !!!  for example: google feeds(except google docs )) ) can't uderstend correct commas but libreOffice, Excel - understand csv file right !

Comment: Man!! you saved me from a lot of headache <3

Answer (score 4):

You can use [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to write, and [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read the file, it automatically converts your string.

A simple example for writing the data:

```
$csv = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
$array = array($csv);
fputcsv($csv, $array);
```

And reading the data:

```
$csv = fopen('file.csv','r');
print_r(fgetcsv($csv));
```

Comment: +1 because imo this is the right way to do it, but providing an example would go a long way to making it a "good" answer.

Comment: `fputcsv` takes an array as the second param.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best answer, but it does work.

You could replace the comma with a random string when inputting to the CSV as below:

```
$commastring = str_replace(",", "/zwdz/", $tempstring);
```

and then when you need to output the comma somewhere on your website (if a database website) you can do the opposite str_replace

Answer (score 0):

You can escape coma like this:

```
$_POST["field"] = str_replace(",", "\,", $_POST["field"]);
```

Or you can put string in quotes

```
$_POST["field"] = "'".$_POST["field"]."'";
```